# Unable to retrieve value from other class method

Tags: android

i have a foll. method in class A

```
 public String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
        // define the columns I want the query to return

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                Phones.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Phones.NUMBER};

        // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(fname));

        // query time
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        // if the query returns 1 or more results
        // return the first result
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
            return name;
        }

        // return the original number if no match was found
        return number;


        }
```

i want to retrive value from the variable fname and insert the value in listview of other class B

Comment: Before that You have to learn basics of Java. Do that properly for at least one weak.

Comment: thanks for your smart suggestion

Comment: This is very very basic question. That is why no one didn't answer you. In stackoverflow no one is ready to teach you. You have to learn, From stackoverflow you can get clarification for your doubts, no one is ready to code for you.

Comment: And unfortunately, your question also not clear.

Comment: And note that, I didn't down vote your question. But you have to learn lot of things to survive in IT industry.

Comment: @Dharmendra User Gunaseelan is right, you should learn Basics of Java, all of us had to do it and if you take not own code, you should be able to adapt it to your needs and without knowing Java is impossible. Crawl before walking and walk before running. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from this method in any public static variable
And then in class B you can write ClassA.name_of_static_variable;

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two classes ClassA and ClassB.
Any method in ClassA that return value so you can get that value in public static variable.
public static String _varName = null; // get you return value in this variable.

And in ClassB you can just write the name of ClassA._varName;
then you can get the value of ClassA in ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

An example with static reference as a bridge communication between classes

//ClassA

```
public class ClassA {
    public static String fName = "";

    public void getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
        //calucate fName value
    }
}
```

//ClassB

```
public class ClassB {
    public static String fName = "";

    private void fromSomeMethod() {
        String fName = ClassA.fName;
    }

}
```